# WPF - MVVM - Textbox getting out of sync with viewmodel property

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, viewmodel

I have a WPF view with a TextBox, binding the Text field to a ViewModel with UpdateSourceTrigger set to PropertyChanged.  In the property setter in the ViewModel, I have a simple check to prevent the text from exceeding 10 characters:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
}


public string Name
{
    get { return _Name; }
    set
    {
        if (_Name != value)
        {
            if (value.Length <= 10)
            {
                _Name = value;
            }
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
}
```

If the value isn't set, I still RaisePropertyChanged (which simply fires PropertyChanged).

The problem is that when I type in the 11th character in the UI, I don't update _Name.  I fire PropertyChanged, and I can see the get accessor get called and it returns the string with only 10 characters.  However, my TextBox doesn't reflect this; it still shows the string with 11 characters.

On top of that, is that if on the 11th character I change the text in the setter to "ERROR", and fire property changed, the TextBox DOES update to show the altered text.

So why is it that if I alter the text in the setter back to the previous value, the UI doesn't reflect this?

I know there are alternative ways of handling max characters, but why won't this work?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is nothing but a bug in the framework. The `Text` property in the `TextBox` does get your new value but the GUI is now out of sync with its own `TextProperty`. This also happends for any `ItemsControl` when you want to cancel a change of `SelectedItem` from the ViewModel and it's really annoying.

This bug doesn't happend when you use explicit `Binding` though so this can be used as a workaround.

*Xaml*

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MyName,
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"
         TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
```

*Code behind*

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
    textBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
}
```

To verify that the TextBox GUI indeed is out of sync, just observe the value of `TextBox.Text`. The `TextBox` will say "123456789___0" for example while `TextBlock` says "123456789".

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Name="myTextBox"
             Text="{Binding Path=MyName,
                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=myTextBox, Path=Text}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Any idea if this has been reported to the mothership?  If not, I will.

Comment: @SteveOsborn: Haha, I'm not sure if this has been reported to the mothership :) I've looked before but I haven't found anything but it's a little hard to know what to search for exactly. Go ahead and report it, let me know when you have and I'll upvote it.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/745368/wpf-textbox-binding-doesnt-work-properly

Comment: Nice, upvoted it. I'll post the workaround to the problem there in a few days after they have responded to it

Comment: @Meleak - Thanks for pointing that out.  I removed my post so not to confuse anyone.

Comment: @JordanParmer: Thx for the upvote. Atleast you got the Disciplined badge for it :) I got that one to in a similar situation