# Bound WPF TextBox is not updating value when the bound property enforces some business rules

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, inotifypropertychanged

I am using .NET 4.0.  I have some very simple code that lets the user type in a number between 1 and 99,999 (inclusive).  I have some logic in the Property setter that prevents the latest value from being applied if it does not adhere to the business rules (e.g., it is not a number or the number is too large).

```
    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Fields

    private string _text = string.Empty;

    #endregion // Fields

    #region Properties

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }

        set
        {
            if (_text == value) return;

            if (IsValidRange(value))
            {
                _text = value;
            }

            OnPropertyChanged("Text");
        }
    }

    #endregion // Properties

    #region Private Methods

    private bool IsValidRange(string value)
    {
        // An empty string is considered valid.
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) return true;

        // We try to convert to an unsigned integer, since negative bill numbers are not allowed,
        // nor are decimal places.
        uint num;
        if (!uint.TryParse(value, out num)) return false;

        // The value was successfully parse, so we know it is a non-negative integer.  Now, we
        // just need to make sure it is in the range of 1 - 99999, inclusive.
        return num >= 1 && num <= 99999;
    }

    #endregion // Private Methods

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion // INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
}
```

The problem I am running into is that when the value is not valid and I just ignore the value, the TextBox bound to this property does not update to reflect that change; rather, it just retains the value as it is typed in.  Here is how I have the property bound:

```
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0"
             Text="{Binding Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I have read a lot of questions that seemed very similar to this, but none of the answers worked for me.  The weird thing is that when I don't validate based on numbers, but just change all text typed in to be upper case, it works just fine.  It just seems to not work when I try to not set the Property to the new value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be a bug with the `TextBox` in .NET 3.5-4.0.  I first tried this in 4.5 and your code worked as written, but when I converted the project to 4.0, I could reproduce the issue.  After doing some searching, I found:

[WPF Textbox refuses to update itself while binded to a view model property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14628424/net-3-5-wpf-textbox-refuses-to-update-itself-while-binded-to-a-view-model-pro), which details a workaround that references:

[Textbox getting out of sync with viewmodel property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837679/wpf-mvvm-textbox-getting-out-of-sync-with-viewmodel-property/10840957#10840957).

Of course if it's possible for you to use .NET 4.5 I'd suggest that, but of course it's not always as easy as that.

Comment: I would love to use .NET 4.5, but it is not really an option for this project.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I had already tried the first link, but I hadn't seen the second one.  The two together are exactly what I needed.  So, for anyone that sees this, implement it exactly as is mentioned in the first link, but make sure your UpdateSourceTrigger is set to Explicit in your binding.