# UI not updated properly for wpf TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a TextBox. In the set and get I have modified the text box value according to my logic. But the UI isn't updated regarding the modification.

```
            <TextBox  
                Width="185"
                Name="TextBoxNumber" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                BorderThickness="0"
                Margin="5, 4, 0, 2"
                Text="{Binding Path=OmukText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
            </TextBox>
```

Here is the set and get

```
    private string _omukText = string.Empty;
    public string OmukText
    {
        get 
        {
            return this._omukText;
        }
        set
        {
            if(value.Equals(" "))
            {
                _omukText = string.Empty;
            }
            if (value.Length > 4 && !value.Contains(" "))
            {
                this._omukText = value.Insert(4, " ");
            }
            else 
            {
                this._omukText = value.Trim();
            }
            this.OnPropertyChanged("OmukText");
        }
    }
```

Suppose, user put a space in the TextBox, according to my setter, the value should be set as an empty string. But in reality the string remains as it was with only a space. The property aren't being changed in the UI. How can I change the UI in real time ? I am open to other options rather than doing in this way.

FYI - I am using .NET 4.0

Comment: Hi, What is your input value? where you given that, I mean UI or VM and   what is your expected answer?

Comment: I am giving input a space in the textbox. In the setter, I have the value of _omukText to empty string, but in the text box it's still showing a space in the textBox.

Comment: I used the same code its working fine with me but used my own OnPropertyChanged method.

Comment: Try to remove UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged from your xaml code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a actually a bug that has been fixed in the .NET Framework 4.5. Please refer to Matt's answer here for more information.

[Bound WPF TextBox is not updating value when the bound property enforces some business rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307554/bound-wpf-textbox-is-not-updating-value-when-the-bound-property-enforces-some-bu)

If you can't upgrade to 4.5 for some reasons you may want to try the workaround suggested here:

[WPF - MVVM - Textbox getting out of sync with viewmodel property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837679/wpf-mvvm-textbox-getting-out-of-sync-with-viewmodel-property/10840957#10840957)

It should be mentioned that the oldest officially supported version of the .NET Framework is currently 4.5.2 so it might be an idea to upgrade after all: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/12/09/support-ending-for-the-net-framework-4-4-5-and-4-5-1/