# WPF binding not working despite correct "using final value"

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

I have a TextBox bound to property MinDuration of the ViewModel. And MinDuration always should be less or equal the Duration property of the ViewModel. So, my XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding BasePO.MinDuration, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

And there is my property:

```
    private double minDuration;
    public double MinDuration
    {
        get { return minDuration; }
        set
        {
            if (value > Duration)
               minDuration = Duration;
            else
                minDuration = value;

            OnPropertyChanged("MinDuration");
        }
    }
```

So, let **Duration = 40**. Now, that is results of binding:

- if I put 4 -> TextBox displays 4
- if then I put 5 (the value is 45 now) -> TextBox displays 40 (Correct!)

But, there is the problem:

- if I put 4 -> TextBox displays 4
- if then I put 0 (the value is 40 now) -> TextBox displays 40
- if then I put, for example, 5 (the value is 405 now) -> TextBox displays 405 (**Why???**)

There is trace of binding:

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 90 : BindingExpression (hash=22334206): Update - got raw value '4'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 93 : BindingExpression (hash=22334206): Update - implicit converter produced '4'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 94 : BindingExpression (hash=22334206): Update - using final value '4'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 102 : BindingExpression (hash=22334206): SetValue at level 1 to PO (hash=59829654) using RuntimePropertyInfo(MinDuration): '4'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=22334206): Got PropertyChanged event from PO (hash=59829654)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=22334206): GetValue at level 0 from PoTableForm (hash=53931641) using RuntimePropertyInfo(BasePO): PO (hash=59829654)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=22334206): GetValue at level 1 from PO (hash=59829654) using RuntimePropertyInfo(MinDuration): '4'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=22334206): TransferValue - got raw value '4'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 84 : BindingExpression (hash=22334206): TransferValue - implicit converter produced '4'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=22334206): TransferValue - using final value '4'
Поток '<Без имени>' (0x19b4) завершился с кодом 0 (0x0).


System.Windows.Data Warning: 90 : BindingExpression (hash=22334206): Update - got raw value '45'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 93 : BindingExpression (hash=22334206): Update - implicit converter produced '45'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 94 : BindingExpression (hash=22334206): Update - using final value '45'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 102 : BindingExpression (hash=22334206): SetValue at level 1 to PO (hash=59829654) using RuntimePropertyInfo(MinDuration): '45'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=22334206): Got PropertyChanged event from PO (hash=59829654)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=22334206): GetValue at level 0 from PoTableForm (hash=53931641) using RuntimePropertyInfo(BasePO): PO (hash=59829654)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=22334206): GetValue at level 1 from PO (hash=59829654) using RuntimePropertyInfo(MinDuration): '40'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=22334206): TransferValue - got raw value '40'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 84 : BindingExpression (hash=22334206): TransferValue - implicit converter produced '40'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=22334206): TransferValue - using final value '40'


System.Windows.Data Warning: 90 : BindingExpression (hash=22334206): Update - got raw value '405'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 93 : BindingExpression (hash=22334206): Update - implicit converter produced '405'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 94 : BindingExpression (hash=22334206): Update - using final value '405'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 102 : BindingExpression (hash=22334206): SetValue at level 1 to PO (hash=59829654) using RuntimePropertyInfo(MinDuration): '405'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=22334206): Got PropertyChanged event from PO (hash=59829654)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=22334206): GetValue at level 0 from PoTableForm (hash=53931641) using RuntimePropertyInfo(BasePO): PO (hash=59829654)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=22334206): GetValue at level 1 from PO (hash=59829654) using RuntimePropertyInfo(MinDuration): '40'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=22334206): TransferValue - got raw value '40'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 84 : BindingExpression (hash=22334206): TransferValue - implicit converter produced '40'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=22334206): TransferValue - using final value '40'
```

As you can see, when I put 405 **using final value '40'**, but TextBox displays 405. And the binding not working for every numbers starting with 40 (in this example).

Comment: Which version of the framework are you targeting?

Comment: My .net version is 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a actually an old bug that has been fixed in the .NET Framework 4.5. Please refer to @Matt's answer here for more information.

[Bound WPF TextBox is not updating value when the bound property enforces some business rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307554/bound-wpf-textbox-is-not-updating-value-when-the-bound-property-enforces-some-bu)

If you can't upgrade to 4.5 for some reasons you may want to try the workaround suggested here:

[WPF - MVVM - Textbox getting out of sync with viewmodel property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837679/wpf-mvvm-textbox-getting-out-of-sync-with-viewmodel-property/10840957#10840957)

It should be mentioned that the oldest officially supported version of the .NET Framework is currently 4.5.2 so it might be an idea to upgrade after all: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/12/09/support-ending-for-the-net-framework-4-4-5-and-4-5-1/